# How to run :pending tests from command line?

Tags: unit-testing, elixir

I sometimes see that tests are taged as `:pending`

```
ExUnit.start
ExUnit.configure(exclude: :pending)

defmodule SublistTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true

  test "empty equals empty" do
    assert Sublist.compare([], []) == :equal
  end

  @tag :pending
  test "empty is a sublist of anything" do
    assert Sublist.compare([], [nil]) == :sublist
  end
end
```

Obviously there are excluded from execution, when you run tests from shell

```
elixir sublist_test.exs
```

Is there a way to include `:pending` test when running tests from command line?

And second question: Why people tag tests as `:pending`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the `mix test` task inside a Mix project. Mix projects are super simple to set up:

```
$ mix new sublist
```

You can specify your default exclusions in `test/test_helper.exs`:

```
ExUnit.start()
ExUnit.configure(exclude: :pending)
```

then you can write your test in `test/sublist_test.exs`. To run the tests, do

```
$ mix test
```

and to include pending tests as well do

```
$ mix test --include pending
```

Now for your second question: people usually mark tests as pending because they are not implemented yet, but they don't want to forget about them. For example you might be on a tight deadline but want to make sure that the tests will eventually be completed. Or maybe the test is not working yet because you need to implement other things first.

If the tests were not excluded by default they would convey the wrong message: that the affected tests are red. But they are rather to do items than actual tests, so they should not fail by default.

Comment: What if I have  only two files. For example: sublist.exs,  sublist_test.exs. I can't  use `mix`, because I don't have `mix.exs`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible out of the box. You could read the command line parameters and then manually feed that into the exunit ocnfiguration, but using a mix project is much easier and less brittle.